# Сервисы для создания скриншота, посредствам url

Tags: php

Делаю бота для проверки результатов ЕГЭ.

Он должен делать скриншоты, юзаю сервис
s-shot.ru

Но...Там оказались ограничения на выдачу скриншотов бесплатно:)

Как не имея своего сервера через другие сервисы сделать скриншот сайта?

Через гугл не предлагать - страницы не индексируются.

Какие знаете аналогичные сервисы?

Comment: Твой вопрос предполагал следующее содержание? , Какие вы знаете сервисы для создания скриншотов сайта? аналогичные s-shot.ru

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов Да, изменил, спасибо.